# Parse data not appearing in iOS 9 Beta 4

Tags: ios, parsing, parse-platform

Since updating to iOS 9 beta 4 it seems that our app can no longer access data in our Parse database - is this a known issue? something others are experiencing?

Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: iOS 9 is not officially supported yet https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/674510916016438/

Comment: @BjörnKaiser - Any plans to release a beta iOS 9 Parse SDK?

Comment: I am not aware of any plans.

Comment: I'm stuck at a solution too, I've added the ATS to the plist and allowed all arbitrary loads, still get no response from Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this domain exception in your *.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>files.parsetfss.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                   <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```